# LivewireScripts not loading correctly

Tags: laravel, scripting, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 10 and Livewire in its latest version (V3.0.10), and it turns out that when the script is loaded (using @livewireScripts) the src points to the server path and not the project path.

`<script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=2f6e5d4d" data-csrf="rrf3uWkSp4zKQUT2dnVelnwxlWQNSOQUPhj1XRu7" data-uri="/livewire/update" data-navigate-once="true"></script>`

That generate a 404 error. Any ideas??

By the way, in the route:list appears the route for livewire and work correctly.